# ForeignKey. "Is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a form validation for my model. This is the model (without useless code) :

```
class Card(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField('lien vers le post', unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', name='catégorie')


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('nom', max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField('description', blank=True)
```

And this is where I get the error (it's in my views.py) :

```
if form.is_valid():
    link = form.cleaned_data['link']
    category_id = form.cleaned_data['category']
    card = Card(link=link, vigil=request.user.profile, category=category_id)
    card.save()
```

The exact error is : `'category' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`
When I searched on Internet, I saw a lot of people with this error but not with a `ForeignKey` but with a `ManyToMany` field.

Comment: Could you have replaced the model `Card` with a different class? To check, add `print(Card)` to your view, to make sure it is the model.

Comment: It's the right class : `<class 'cards.models.Card'>`

Comment: What's your form? `ModelForm`? if so, you can just do `form.save()`, you don't need to manually create `Card`.

Comment: It doesn't use a ModelForm, just a Form...

Comment: Is that the actual code that defines the `category` field? I don't think that model fields have a `name` argument.

Comment: Why can't it have a name argument? I defined it like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `category = models.ForeignKey('Category', name='catégorie')`

Use `category = models.ForeignKey(Category, name='catégorie')`

And when creating the card try:

```
category = Category.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['category'])
card = Card(link=link, vigil=request.user.profile, category=category)
```

Also make sure you correct your model-order: First define the Category-, then the Card model.

When you've done this, replace `name=...` in your model with `verbose_name=...`

Hope this helps :D

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'Category' is not defined` they are in the same file however....

Comment: In the views? What's your import?

Comment: Nope, in the models ! `category = models.ForeignKey(Category, name='catégorie')`. I use Django 1.9...

Comment: Okay. Then it's caused by your model-order. Define your Category model before defining your card-model :)

Comment: Okay nice, so now I can write `category = models.ForeignKey(Category, name='catégorie')`, but still the same error :-( `'category' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: Could you post your complete models.py file? It looks like you try to define the model inside of a method.

Comment: Did you migrate your model correctly and restarted your server?

Comment: ok. What happens if you remove the name argument from the ForeignKey?

Comment: Maybe try using `verbose_name=...`

Comment: It... WORKS! Genious! Thanks a lot!